Can we use calculus for graph theory?
I was thinking about how to specify an algorithm for planarity of a graph. The obvious very direct (but inefficient) approach would simply be to try to position the vertices at every possible point and checking for intersections. We could limit it to points on a integer lattice $\Lambda$ without any loss.
So for example if the Adjacency matrix is M of a graph of N nodes, the test of planarity would be if the following function is zero:
$$P(M)=\prod\limits_{X\in \mathbb{Z}^{2N}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \sum\limits_{l=1}^NM_{ij}M_{kl}\phi(X_i,Y_j,Z_k,W_l)$$
Where $\phi$ is a function which counts the intersections between the line-sements XY and ZW. In other words, it is zero if the line XY doesn't cross the line ZW (and all XYZ,W are different) and some positive number otherwise. Which is just some polynomial inequalities on X,Y,Z and W each from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ on the lattice.
I haven't really seen this approach before. (Perhaps because it is not practical or useful!). But I was wondering if this analytic approach to graph theory is known to lead anywhere interesting? The infinite sum over lattice points reminds me a bit of theta functions or rational solutions of algebraic equations.
Also, probably we could limit ourselves to a lattice of size $2^N$ in width and height(?)

Note that polynomials behave quite differently in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ than in $\mathbb{R}^n$: for example, whether a polynomial has a real solution is decidable but whether a polynomial has an integer solution is as complicated as the halting problem (this is the MRDP theorem/Hilbert's 10th problem; I'm assuming here that polynomials in each case have integer coefficients). More relevantly to this question, calculus only (directly) makes sense in the $\mathbb{R}$-setting.

This is not to say that calculus can't be used in discrete settings - witness analytic number theory -simply that it's more complicated.
